# TypeScript keyof of nested object type

Tags: typescript

I want to get a union of all the keys under `on` in this object type inferred from a configuration object:

```
type Config = {
initial: string;
states: {
    idle: {
        on: {
          START: string;
        };
        effect(): void;
    };
    running: {
        on: {
            PAUSE: string;
        };
        effect(): void;
    };
    paused: {
        initial: string;
        states: {
            frozen: {
                on: {
                    HEAT: string;
                };
            };
        };
        on: {
          RESET: string;
        };
    };
};
```

}

Note that the configuration can have nested `on` keys under `states`. Right now I can get the first level keys using:

```
type KeysOfTransition<Obj> = Obj extends Record<PropertyKey, any> ? keyof Obj : never;
type TransitionKeys = KeysOfTransition<Config["states"][keyof Config["states"]]["on"]>
// "START" | "PAUSE" | "RESET"
```

But I cannot get `HEAT` in the union, which is nested. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the second lv `on` always under the second lv `states`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There may well be edge cases, but here's an implementation that works for your example:

```
type KeysUnder<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
  T extends object ? {
    [P in keyof T]-?: (P extends K ? keyof T[P] : never) | KeysUnder<T[P], K>
  }[keyof T] : never;
    
type ConfigOnKeys = KeysUnder<Config, "on">;
// type ConfigOnKeys = "START" | "PAUSE" | "RESET" | "HEAT"
```

The idea is to use a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) to drill down into object properties.  To get `KeysUnder<T, K>`, for an object `T`, we look at each property key `P`.  If `P` matches `K` (which will be `"on"` in your use case), then you want the keys of its the property value type `T[P]`.  The recursive bit is that we also join all these keys to `KeysUnder<T[P], K>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmUC8UDeBYAKCihQRWBQEMAbALigGdgAnUtAbkOKcuAgfr4ixEgBNqEQVxHFEU4TOIBlACoBBAEor6TVgg7SZAX04KREJEggBjYAAoAlPQBucFKNPHPI5gFcEZPryilByuIaKAApqAKpKAKI6LGzeXhHEFla2ji5uHhEmEWCUvgwQosGKpORUdIzJ+qkiPHwC4WYySMxwAF4QCJUhsgPtQ4oAEvFq2vV6Bh2KhQvESyGrimFCYxrxCTO6KelQ6yveS0aEhKCQUADSECAMMQiiEMwAPCoANHdQEAAefBeDCgkW6kGYoHuIAAfFhpCo-oD+qIQXAAEYAKxswCgAH5RiIANqREgIKAAawecCQUBUAF0ALR4+h2UkAoGo34EqkgGl0kn0qD0BAQZxvBxQAA+dweTxeb0+gp+txh0iMRN5-IZwqgovFzFMV3A0HgyHQAHkENCQdgbc9Xh8zag0D8AESIN0w0wAeh9UGupsQLqtNqwUDdqk0Kjd0oj0Ti8VjMrdOz2yYjk2mbqAA)

Comment: This works perfectly - I'm getting a "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite." when feeding ConfigOnKeys to other functions, but I can figure it out.

Comment: Yes, recursive conditional types do have issues, and possible infinite regress is one of them.  There are techniques to try to prevent that from happening, but without a [mcve] it's hard to know how to advise.